# How to send multiple serialized java objects as get parameters?

Tags: java, serialization

I have multiple serializable java objects and I need to send this objects with get parameter like;

```
www.example.com?objects=rO0ABXNyACl0ci5iaXp......
```

How can I send these objects?

Currently I am trying to use comma("%2C") to seperate objects but I don't know If Java can use "%2C" when trying to serialize object.

```
String serializedObject1 = "sf21adada....";
String serializedObject2 = "nfg312111....";
String serializedObject3 = "mjhgfffff....";

String URL = "www.example.com?objects=" + serializedObject1 + "%2C" + serializedObject2  + "%2C" + serializedObject3;
```

**EDIT:** I have some application which sends an object over http request and I need to update this application to support sending multiple objects. Here is main code;

```
String serializedObject = URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeObject(myObject), "UTF-8");
URL = "www.example.com?objects=" + serializedObject;
makeRequest(URL);
```

Comment: Serialization doesn't produce a string. It produces bytes. You first need to transform these bytes to printable characters, and then urlencode them. But passing serialized Java objects, and even more as query string parameters, looks like a terrible idea to me. And BTW, the query string is limited in length. What are you trying to achieve? Why are you doing this?

Comment: You want to serialize into JSON for example. And then you look into expressing your data in that format.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet. This seems like a truly terrible idea. *At least* send them as POST arguments in the body of the request. But you should really decouple your HTTP requests from the host language you're using.

Comment: That said, to send multiple parameters with the same name, the syntax is `?objects=blabla&objects=foo&objects=bar`. You are already correctly transforming your bytes to strings and urlencoding the result, so just joining them as I just explain will work fine (unless they're too large). But really, you shouldn't be sending serialized Java objects over HTTP, and certainly not as query string parameters.

Comment: You are also in severe danger of running into URL length limits wherever you go.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a JSON Serializer like Genson in order to serialize your POJO.
However, be careful because there is a maximum size for the GET parameter (that can normally be configured with the server itself). Therefore, you might want to consider using POST method.
Here is a code sample that should work in order to send your objects :

```
List<MyTypeOrSyperType> list = new ArrayList<MyTypeOrSuperType>();
...
String json = genson.serialize(list);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```